# Improve performance to render tiles from Geoserver on Google map

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, postgis, geoserver, wms

I have started using Geoserver and PostgreSQL combination to render polygons (more than 4000) on Google Map. Everything seems to be fine. However, when I zoom the map, layers are redrawn very slowly on browser. These polygons are not fixed.I get information about which polygons need to be displayed from a web page and then from PostGresql view. Therefore I have passed viewParams in WMS service of Geoserver.
I use Geowebcache. But the problem I described above does not solve from GeoWebcache. Is there anything that I can try to improve performance?

Thanks.

Comment: You may have more answers on the [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: OK. I will copy the same question to GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: Copied the same question on GIS Stack Exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247316/improve-performance-to-render-tiles-from-geoserver-on-google-map